# Slick extension for H2 database to support array datatype

Tags: database, scala, h2, slick

I have a use case in slick where the abcId in the below code is an Array[String] which is not supported in Slick. Is there any extensions for it? We are using H2 database.
Any help is appreciated.

```
class someTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[(UUID, Array[String], Timestamp)](tag, “Some”) {
    def xyzId: Rep[UUID]         = column[UUID]("xyz_id")
    **def abcId: Rep[Array[String]]              = column[Array[String]](“abc_id", O.Length(500))**
    def createdTimestamp: Rep[Timestamp] = column[Timestamp]("created_timestamp")
    def * : ProvenShape[(UUID,Array[String], Option[UUID],
      String, Timestamp)] = (xyzId, abcId, createdTimestamp)
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We ended up achieving this by writing our own JdbcType for Seq[String] and an extension which supports the H2 array functions.

https://gist.github.com/sundaram161989/d7a639f5d1e2e183fbdf8626c88d2f7f